# How to store the content for android application

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm a complete newbie in android development with some basic programming knowledge. Right now, I want to develop an E-Commerce app which allows the user to upload pictures for the public to browse through. However, I have no idea how should I store all the data, including the details(username and password) of the user, in the server. As far as I know, the database most often used in android is SQLite, but I'm not sure whether it's suitable to be used in my case.

Please shed some light. Any form of help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set-up a backend using some database (eg. [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)) and some programming language (eg. [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)) as well as some kind of web-server (eg. [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache)).

You would store the products,user data in tables of the database. Pictures would be stored on some directory on your server and you could store references to their path in the respective fields.

Your client (android) would load the products list as well as submit new products via issuing requests to your server back end, and perhaps store them in some SQLite database if you need the old items viewed to remain viewable without an internet connection.

A few tutorials to get you started:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! I'll definitely look into those links provided. Btw, I've also found out that MongoDB is also a viable solution. Do you have any thought about it?

Answer (score 0):

If you'll create an e-commerce mobile app, it cannot exists as a mobile app alone because it needs to connect to other users. You need to integrate it to a web service or a cloud service to tasks such as getting the item data, images, and other tasks involved. There are Baas (cloud) that you can use such as Parse and Kinvey.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Do you think Parse is easier compared to the MySQL+PHP way?

Comment: Yes, because most of the features that you probably need is already available, you just need to use it. Also, you don't need to maintain the backend codes. There are some disadvantage in using Baas is that you can't customize what the service offers and you can't create a new features that your mobile application needs